# Jquery change hidden input value in for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I try to change each hidden input value if checkbox is checked using jquery

I need to using for loop because html input field is generate by php loop from db too. so here is generated html code look like :

Html :

```
<input id="gift0" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true0" value="" type="hidden">

<input id="gift1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true1" value="" type="hidden">

<input id="gift2" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true2" value="" type="hidden">
```

Jquery :

```
   var tot = <?php echo $tot; ?>;

   jQuery(function($){
     for (var i = 0; i< tot; i++ ){
       var chk = '#gift' + i;

       var val = '#gift-true' + i;
       $(chk).change(function(e) {
         for (var a = 0; a<= jml; a++ ){
         $(val).val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
         }
         console.log(e);
       });
     }
  });
```

but this code didn't work.

P.S :

code to generate html input is look like this :

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' id='gift$i' name='exm$i' value='1'> <br>
       <input type='hidden' id='gift-true$i' value=''></td> <br><br>";
}
```

Comment: your code is incorrect ,why do you need hidden inputs, how do you trigger this code?

Comment: because i need to get value even if the checkbox i not checked

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `next()` function as all the inputs are next to the checkbox. please replace `var tot = 3;` with `var tot = <?php echo $tot; ?>;` and `type="text"` with `type="hidden"`

```js
var tot = 3;

   jQuery(function($){
     for (var i = 0; i< tot; i++ ){
       $('#gift' + i).on('change', function(e) {
         $(this).next().val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
       });
     }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="gift0" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true0" value="no" type="text">

<input id="gift1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true1" value="no" type="text">

<input id="gift2" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true2" value="no" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes this two value in your code

```
var chk = $('#gift' + i).val();
var val = $('#gift-true' + i).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what u want i guess

```
var tot = 3;

 jQuery(function($){
 for (var i = 0; i< tot; i++ ){
   $('#gift' + i).on('change', function(e) {
     $(this).next().val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
   });
 }
 });
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="gift0" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true0" value="no" type="text">
<input id="gift1" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true1" value="no" type="text">
<input id="gift2" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id="gift-true2" value="no" type="text">
```

Comment: it didn't work but if i change 
$('#gift-true0').val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");

it works but still i need to change each hidden input based on checkbox

Comment: Hey go with the answer given by @jafarbtech

Comment: yeah it's worked now but i give the first one choise answer

BTW thanks a lot @Rasika :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var tot = <?php echo $tot; ?>;

   jQuery(function($){
     for (var i = 0; i< tot; i++ ){
       var chk = $('#gift' + i);

       var val = $('#gift-true' + i);
       $(chk).change(function(e) {
         for (var a = 0; a<= jml; a++ ){
         $(val).val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
         }
         console.log(e);
       });
     }
  });
```

You need to get `object` instead of `string` right now you are getting a `string` which is `'#gift' + i`. Wrap it inside `$('#gift' + i)` to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

Only relevant input should be set on change of a checkbox. You should not loop again for each input on change event.

```
var tot = <?php echo $tot; ?>;

   jQuery(function($){
     for (var i = 0; i< tot; i++ ){
       $('#gift' + i).on('change', function(e) {
           // no need for another loop as you should target only relevant input field
           $('input#gift-true' + i).val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
       });
     }
   });
```

Comment: check your value of tot?

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need loop here. Just change the value of the next input.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    var $hidden = $(this).next('input[type="hidden"]');
    if ($hidden.length) {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checked) {
             $hidden.val('yes');
        } else {
             $hidden.val('no');
        }
    }
});

//call function for every checkbox which are already on page
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change();
```

This code will work for every checkbox on the page. To avoid this just use stronger selector: `$('.some-class input[type="checkbox"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Change you id to class

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
 echo "<input type='checkbox' class='gift' name='exm$i' value='1'> <br>
       <input type='hidden' name='gift-exm$i' class='gift-true' value=''></td> <br><br>";
}
```

refactor your code as follows

```
 $('.gift').change(function(e) {//remove any loops /keep the change event
         var el = $(this);
        el.next('.gift-true').val(el.is(':checked') ? "yes" : "no");//select the hidden input using next()
 });
```

ps: don't forget to add a name to the hidden input

```js
$('.gift').change(function(e) {
             var el = $(this);
            el.next('.gift-true').val(el.is(':checked') ? "yes" : "no");
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="gift" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input class="gift-true" value="no" type="text">

<input class="gift" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input class="gift-true" value="no" type="text">

<input class="gift" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input class="gift-true" value="no" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer, similar to a few others, also eliminates the for loop.

```
            jQuery(function ($) {
                // do this if you do not know the state of the generated checkbox
                $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {

                    $(this).next().val($(this).prop("checked") ? "yes" : "no");
                });

                // then this for your event handler
                $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function (e) {
                    $(e.target).next().val($(e.target).prop("checked")?"yes":"no");
                })
            });
```